# Django naturaltime Localization error

Tags: python, django, localization

My language ID is 'id'. I used localized humanize library for my Django template tags and use the `naturaltime`, but the translation is partially wrong. The `now` translated to `sekarang` is right. `second` to `detik`. `minute` to `menit`, but when it comes to `date`, `week`, or `months`, the word is not translated to my language. It keeps printing `date`, `week`, and `months`.

Here are my Django configuration

```
TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Jakarta'
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'id'
SITE_ID = 1
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True
USE_TZ = True
```

Here how I used the naturaltime template tags.

```
<time class="discussion__info__item">{{ object.created|naturaltime }}</time>
```

Do I forgot something? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately translations for day = hari, week = minggu, month = bulan, year = tahun etc. are missing in the `.../site-packages/django/contrib/humanize/locale/id/LC_MESSAGES/django.[mp]o` gettext files.

You could add translations yourself.

Comment: Could explain how to add the translations? Thank you.

Comment: See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/internals/contributing/localizing/ and https://www.transifex.com/projects/p/django/

Answer (score 1):

Missing translations on `full-path-to../django/conf/locale/id/LC_MESSAGES/django.po`.

Search weeks, month and any other string you want to translate on that file, then translate at  the line msgstr. Example,

```
#: utils/timesince.py:27
#, python-format
msgid "%d day"
msgid_plural "%d days"
msgstr[0] "%d hari"
```

After that, convert to `django.mo` using any tools (you can use online tools like http://po2mo.net). Don't forget to restart django apps to see the changes. Good luck.